# Select JSON objects with key matching one of many values using jq

Tags: json, jq

Let's say I have a few JSON objects in a Bash variable :

```
json='{"key":"100"}{"key":"200"}{"key":"300"}'
```

To select the object with `key` matching `100` I can do :

```
printf '%s\n' "$json" | jq 'select ( .key == "100" )'
```

As @axiac pointed out in the comments, I can use `or` to match one of several values.

```
printf '%s\n' "$json" | jq 'select(.key == "100" or .key == "200")
```

But what if I need to match `key` against a larger number of values, in which case using `or` becomes cumbersome?

What code would select all objects with `key` matching a value between 99 and 201?

Comment: `jq 'select(.key == "100" or .key == "200")`. Read the [`jq` documentation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) for more ideas.

Comment: `printf` is not needed, `echo "$json"` is enough. `printf` is slower.

Comment: @axiac What if I wish to match one of so many values that `or` is not a viable option?

Answer (score 1):

> select all objects with key matching a value between 99 and 201?

Interpreting "between" as "strictly between", one way would be:

```
 select(.key | tonumber | 99<. and .<201 )
```

> to match one of several values

When it's possible to specify the values as a stream, one can also use `IN/1`:

```
 select(.key | tonumber | IN(range(100;200)))
```

Of course in the present case, the first solution above (using '<') would be more efficient.

Comment: Today I learned that `jq` provides both an [`in()` function](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#in) and a so-called ["SQL-style `IN()` operator"](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#SQL-StyleOperators). Thank you.

Comment: Yes, your answer would have been fine (as an answer to to the original Q) with IN/1.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf '%s\n' "$json" |jq 'select((.key|tonumber >=100) and (.key|tonumber <=200))'
```